# difference between expression/look on her face?

Tags: word-choice, difference

She had a sad expression/look on her face.

Are these completely interchangeable? Which is more common?

Answer (score 3):

They are equivalent in that context. Both seem like complicated ways to say "She looked sad."

Answer (score 0):

Use of the noun "expression" or "look" depends on intended meaning.

> Expression: a look on someone’s face that shows what their thoughts or feelings are
>
> Look:  an expression that you have on your face or in your eyes

These could be interchangeable, but in your sample question "She had a sad expression/look on her face", "look" seems to be the most commonly used in speech.  However, since the facial expression is defined (by "sad"), "She had a sad expression on her face" would be more definitive, especially in written language.

Comment: _Look_ can mean the appearance of anything, not specifically a person's face.

Comment: My car has a dilapidated look, and, as far as I am aware, it has neither face nor eyes.

Comment: The OP asked specifically about use of expression/look on one's face.  So I do not understand why your concerns are application of "look" to other things.  That is irrelevant here.

Comment: You’ve defined each of *expression* and *look* in terms of the other. That’s not a good way to help someone understand any difference between them.